# Problema ao importar arquivo texto via VBA

Tags: vba, csv, macro

Estou tentando importar um arquivo texto para o excel através da seguinte macro:

```
Sub Teste()

    Dim intervalo As String
    intervalo = "intervalo"

    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Plan1").Select

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Desktop\ArquivoCSV.csv", Destination:= _
        Range("$A$1"))
        .CommandType = 1
        .Name = intervalo
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    Range("intervalo").Select

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="testeCSV"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Porem quando debugando, ao chegar no `.CommandType = 1` acontece um erro e não estou conseguindo identificar qual o problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E qual é o erro que ele mostra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não deve utilizar o CommandType para importação de arquivos textos, como é o seu caso.

Veja no Help traduzido da Microsoft:

> Você pode definir a propriedade CommandType somente se o valor da propriedade QueryType da tabela de consulta ou o cache de tabela dinâmica for xlOLEDBQuery.

Note que, como eu disse, esse não é o seu caso, já que você não está fazendo uma query em um banco de dados, por exemplo.

Comment: Ok, eu gravei a macro e não sabia nem por onde começar, mas realmente era esse o problema, obrigado.